# Forms authentication using different login pages for different parts of app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

I am working on an ASP.Net MVC 3 app that has a public face and a private, Admin face.

Users do not have to be authenticated to use the public face, until they have to commit and make payments, and then they have to sign in/create an account.

The Admin face is also secured.  To use it, you need to be logged in.  Authentication is done using an enterprise-wide authentication system.  But the public will not be authenticated using that system:  their authentication is done using a more simple database-based system.

I am still figuring out what this would involve, but right now my question is:  is it possible to set up Forms Authentication so that, depending on what you are trying to access, you get directed to one of two different login pages?  That use different authentication mechanisms?

Comment: Why don't you separate them in 2 different applications?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov That is an excellent question.

Comment: You can see this response http://stackoverflow.com/a/5911214/7720

Comment: @Romias  That's exactly what I needed to see!  (Assuming we don't split this into two apps, as Darin suggested).

Comment: @Romias If you want to post this as an answer I'll give you the credit.

Comment: @AnnL., don't worry... just +1 the comment if you like!

Comment: You should post it as an answer so this question can be properly closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was answered by Romias, in the comments.  He referred me to this question and answer:

[Having different login pages for different ASP.NET MVC 3 areas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911092/having-different-login-pages-for-different-asp-net-mvc-3-areas/5911214#5911214).

This gave me exactly what I needed.