# Forms Authentication with Multiple MVC Areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have a simple task to accomplish, I am creating an application that has two types of users, `Admins` and `Users`.

I looked at this: [ASP.NET MVC 3 Areas and multiple authentication in web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8176703/asp-net-mvc-3-areas-and-multiple-authentication-in-web-config)

And it is very close to what I need to do.

So the simple question is how do you have different login schemes using Forms Authentication in different areas on an MVC site?

Comment: Here is the answer of your Question 

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911092/having-different-login-pages-for-different-asp-net-mvc-3-areas][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911092/having-different-login-pages-for-different-asp-net-mvc-3-areas

Answer (score 3):

putting security attributes in web.config many not be the best thing to do as explained by the post [How can we set authorization for a whole area in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319157/how-can-we-set-authorization-for-a-whole-area-in-asp-net-mvc). Please consider applying attributes at the controller level eg

```
[Authorize(Roles = "User, Administrator")]
```

or

```
[Authorize(Roles = "User")]
```

or

```
[Authorize(Roles = "User, Administrator")]
```

Happy Coding